# Updating WSDL Reference but web config is not updated in ASP.net MVC 4 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, wsdl

I am using Visual Studio 2013 in my mvc web Appln project,wsdl was added, When i am adding new wsdl file using 'Add Service Reference' in project then respective bindings tags are not created in web.config file .

> I read many blogs and post but didnt got any solution:
>
> 1. i tried unchecking 'Reuse Types' the tick when we Select 'Add Web Reference'
> 2. also saw this blog [carlos figueira](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2012/03/25/mixing-add-service-reference-and-wcf-web-http-a-k-a-rest-endpoint-does-not-work/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem you have, I think.

In my case I was trying to "add service reference" from a WCF service I had configured (in web.config of the service) to get a json response like 
http://.../getjson/getProducts

and the web.config for this was:

```
...
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
  <endpoint address="getjson" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" contract="ws.IProduct"/>
...
```

after remove this, when I "add service reference" it updates the web.config as always.

i hope it helps for you problem.